# Getting wslite.http.HTTPClientException: 404 Not Found. Verified the Soap Address is correct

Tags: groovyws

I am using groovy wslite plugin to make a soap call. I am getting wslite.http.HTTPClientException: 404 Not Found. Can someone help me to debug the issue.

Groovy code

```
    def client = new SOAPClient(Helper.getConfigValue('grails.soap.ws.url'))

    try {
        def response = client.send(SOAPAction: SOAP_NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_START_PROCESS,
                sslTrustAllCerts: true) {
            header {
                delegate.securityInfo(buildSecurityInfoObject())
            }
            body {
                getNotificationRequest('xmlns': SOAP_NAMESPACE) {
                    delegate.transactionId('12345')
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did this alredy, here I ask anyway: Have you verified that the resource exists under the path/url you are trying to retrieve it from? 
404 often indicate that the host is not available.